# How to calculate closing balance for each trans_date in oracle query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

1. Here i want closing balance for each `trans_date` so that closing balance associated with `last_trans_date` would be my closing balance for the month.
2. sample table:

---

```
TRANS_DAT     CREDIT      DEBIT
--------- ---------- ----------
24-SEP-18       2500        400
24-SEP-18                   200
24-SEP-18        500
30-SEP-18        400       1200
30-SEP-18        400
```

I used following query:

```
SELECT TRANS_DATE, SUM(NVL(CREDIT,0)-NVL(DEBIT,0)) BALANCE  
  FROM BANK_TRANS GROUP BY TRANS_DATE;
```

output:

```
TRANS_DATE    BALANCE
---------  ----------
24-SEP-18       2400
30-SEP-18       -400
```

however the closing balance for `30-SEP-18` should be `2000.00` as correct month ending closing balance but i got closing balance for that day only.

Please help me out with the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you group by each date, you will get one row for each date. If you use the `trunc()` [function](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php) you can get rows and values per month:

```
SELECT trunc(TRANS_DATE,'MONTH'), SUM(NVL(CREDIT,0)-NVL(DEBIT,0)) BALANCE 
FROM BANK_TRANS 
GROUP BY trunc(TRANS_DATE,'MONTH');
```